# C# string to combobox issues

Tags: c#, type-conversion

What i'm trying to do is read in a header row of a file to a combobox.  Here is my code:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] startdelim = File.ReadAllLines(textBox1.Text);
    int counter = 1;
    foreach (string delim in startdelim)
    {
        if (counter == 1)
        {
            string removedelim = delim.Replace("\"", "");
            string[] lines = removedelim.IndexOf(",");
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(line);
            }
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

for some reason it keeps telling me

> Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string[]' at `string[] lines = removedelim.IndexOf(",");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IndexOf` returns the first index of the string `","` within `removedelim`. You're looking for `Split`.

```
string[] lines = 
    removedelim.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Note that there is not an instance of `Split` that takes a single `string` (since some languages allow implicit conversion between `string` and `char[]`, which would make overload resolution ambiguous and not easily corrected), so you have to use the overload that takes an array of delimiters and just provide one.

Answer (score 0):

Well the error is pretty straightforward. `IndexOf` returns the integer position of the character you searched for. You need to do a `Split` instead of `IndexOf`.

Answer (score 0):

[String. IndexOf(Char)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd.aspx) : Reports the index of the first occurrence of the specified Unicode character in this string.

sting.IndexOf(char) returns a int not a sting array.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already spotted the mistake. Still there are problems with your code. All you need is following lines of code:

```
string[] startdelim = File.ReadAllLines(textBox1.Text);
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(startdelim[0].Replace("\","").Split(","));
```

Comment: While this is more succinct (and, indeed, "better"), this isn't a "problem" with his code.